# PHP - Ensure GET request is from specific domain

Tags: php

I am getting an image link from an HTML GET request like this...

```
www.example.com?image=www.anotherdomain.com/image.jpg

if (isset($_GET['image'])) {
    echo $_GET['image'];
}
```

How can I ensure that the image URL that is passed comes from www.anotherdomain.com

Should I parse the URL and check that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `parse_url` with second argument set to `PHP_URL_HOST`

```
<?php

$image = $_GET['image'];
$host = parse_url($image, PHP_URL_HOST);
if ($host !== 'abc.xyz') {
    # error
    return;
}

# your logic
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

P.S. Make sure you check that `$_GET['image']` exists to avoid notices.

Answer (score 3):

You should do it with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['image'])) {
    $hostname = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if ($hostname == "anotherdomain.com") {
        echo $_GET['image'];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the image is always from the same website, you could just check for the first part of the url and if it matches your desired url, use it, otherwise dont use it.

```
$url = 'www.anotherdomain.com';
$image = $_GET['image'];
$substr = substr($image, 0, strlen($url) - 1);

if ($substr === $url) {
    // yay
}
else {
    // nope
}
```